# Cannot install npm module for Azure mobile app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, npm-install, kudu

Can someone help me to install node.js module for Azure mobile app ?

I want to use azure-storage in my Azure mobile app.
I tried the following two ways and got same error:
  1. Install in kudu terminal  (npm install "azure-storage")
  2. Add "dependencies" module in package json and push from local git ("azure-storage": ">=1.1.0")

```
remote: npm ERR! node v4.2.3
remote: npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
remote: npm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure-storage
remote: npm ERR! code EPERM
remote: npm ERR! errno -4048
remote: npm ERR! syscall rename
remote: Failed exitCode=-4048, command="D:\Program Files     (x86)\nodejs\4.2.3\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.5.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
remote:
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure-storage' -> 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.azure-storage.DELETE'
remote: npm ERR!     at Error (native)
remote: npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure-storage' -> 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.azure-storage.DELETE']
remote: npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
remote: npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
remote: npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
remote: npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\azure-storage',
remote: npm ERR!   dest: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\.azure-storage.DELETE',
remote: npm ERR!   parent: 'azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts.backend.node.EmptySite' }
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote: npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

Before I met this error today, I used "npm install" in kudu terminal and everything looks okay.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Appreciate for any help, THANKS.

UPDATE package.json

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "=4.2.1"
  },
  "name": "azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts.backend.node.EmptySite",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "amax_version": "2.0.19.160727",
  "description": "Samples for Azure Mobile Apps",
  "author": "Microsoft",
  "repository": "Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.0",
    "azure-mobile-apps": "^2.1.0",
    "azure-storage": "^1.1.0",
    "sendgrid": "^3.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: why do u want to do that in kudu terminal? you build the application that using node js sdk for azure mobile services and then host it in azure. right ?

Comment: I can successfully install the azure-storage package using package.json and doing a git deployment. I suspect this is a transient issue, does it occur every time you try to deploy? If you try a deployment against a newly created Web App or Mobile App, does it occur?

Comment: Hi Aravind, yes, all on Azure.  Hi @Dale Anderson, It occurs every time I tried on this server. I tried another server and deploy successfully.

Comment: Do you set any specific  application settings in this mobile app?

Comment: Hi Gary, I didn't set something special. It seems something wrong with azure-storage. I tried another npm package (sendgrid) and deploy successfully.

Comment: But you can successfully deploy azure-storage in another azure mobile apps server, right? Could you please provided your `package.json` file in the problem application?

Comment: Yes, success in another mobile app server.  I posted my package.json, thanks.

Comment: Any reason you are setting the node version in your package.json? I don't think it would cause errors in the npm install, but it could. If you remove the engines node, it will default to version 4.2.3.

Comment: Hi @DaleAnderson, the node version is not added by myself. I tried to remove this and still got the same error when deploy, thanks.

Comment: No worries, I realised this is listed in the package.json from the quickstart. This issue is a mystery! I would clone your site using git, delete the site in the portal, recreate it and push the content back.